# Let $z = e^{ \frac {2\pi i}{7}} $ and let $p = z+z^2+z^4 $.Then which of the following options are correct?

Tags: field-theory

Let $z= e^{ \frac {2\pi i}{7}} $ and let $p= z+z^2+z^4 $ then

1. $p$ is in $ \mathbb {Q} $
2. $p$ is in $ \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt {D}) $ for some $D \gt 0$
3. $p$ is in $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt {D}) $ for some $D \lt 0$
4. $p$ is in  $i \mathbb {R} $

Option  $1$ is clearly false.  please give me some hints for other options.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up Gauss sums. [This local search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Gauss+sum%22+7) should give you enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$p^2=z^2+z^4+z+2z^3+2z^5+2z^6=-p-2+2(1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6)$$
and $1+z+\cdots+z^6=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $p^\ast=z^6+z^5+z^3=z^2p$ and $z^2\ne\pm1$, $p$ is neither real nor imaginary. eliminating $1$, $2$ and $4$. As Lord Shark the Unknown already noted, $p^2+p+2\implies p=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-7}}{2}$ so option $3$ is correct.

Comment: why $ p= \frac {-1+\sqrt {-7}}{2} $ @J.G. ,please explain,  I can't understand how you delete the possibility that p can be $ \frac {-1-\sqrt {-7}}{2} $

Comment: @suchandaadhikari Sorry, I meant to write $\pm$ there, which I do as of my latest edit. We don't need to determine the sign to work out which options are applicable.

Comment: yes but is it possible to determine the sign easily?

Comment: @suchandaadhikari In general, no! Gauss himself spent a while figuring out the correct sign (for primes much larger than $7$), even though the solution is in many a book now. For $7$th roots of unity it is easy. Draw them on the complexplane. Surely you can figure which side of the real axis the sum is!

Comment: Thank you sir  I will do it.